# "to underline" as a noun. Is it "an underlining"?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

The word "*a lining*" has got nothing to do with drawn lines (it's something about fur and fabrics apparently...). There is also no verb "*to line*" that means "the act of drawing a line".

But there *does* exist the verb "*to **under**line*" which means "the act of drawing a line under words in a text". What is the corresponding noun? Is "*an underlining*" correct? As in:

> When I underline important words I make a nice underlining.

Comment: The example is always going to be a bit "awkward", whether you use the relatively uncommon simple noun ***underline*** or the gerund noun ***underlining***. Both are syntactically valid, but I think most people would rather avoid the awkwardness by switching to something like ***...I do it nicely.***

Comment: I agree with the answer in the previous comment- "I do it nicely" sounds much more natural.

Comment: When I underline words, I underline nicely. My underlining is nice. Underline can also mean emphasize.

Comment: Assuming the intended meaning of "nice" here is "neat, straight", you could even get away with *When I underline important words I make **it** straight*. Strictly speaking that's syntactically "defective", in that ***it*** has no preceding ***noun*** to refer back to, but it would naturally be understood as representing *the product / outcome / result of the aforementioned act of underlining*.

Answer (score 1):

The gerund of *to underline* is ***underlining***. This is the noun that refers to the action.

You can also use ***underline*** as a noun in itself, to refer to the line itself that appears under the text. So, it depends on which sense you want for the noun.

> In **underlining** the text, she was careful to make the **underline** straight.

However, in many cases people will just use the word *line*. You only need to say *underline* as a noun in these cases where you need to be clear that you are talking about the line under the text.

So, in your example, you want either *line* or *underline*. *Line* would be more natural to me. Using the gerund there is not completely unheard of, but would be unusual and seem wrong to many native speakers.

Answer (score 0):

"underline" could be used as a noun in your case:

See definition 4 under "noun" here - "a line drawn under something; an underscore.":
https://www.dictionary.com/browse/underline

But "underlining," as @FumbleFingers points out, can also be used as a noun. I would prefer "underline" in your sentence but "underlining" could also work.

Comment: From [T.S. Eliot and the Poetics of Evolution:](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22his+underlining+of+the+phrase%22) *Eliot's enthusiastic acceptance of this idea is suggested by his **underlining** of the phrase and by his marginal comment, "grand".* It's *possible* to use ***underline*** as a noun in other contexts, but I'd say the example I've cited is essentially a "gerund noun" rather than a "continuous verb form". In my example, ***underline*** simply doesn't work at all, but either form is possible in OP's cited context.

Comment: Agree - didn't think of that - updated my response.